# Set response headers in jasmine-ajax mock responses?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-ajax

How do I set the response headers in `respondWith` with jasmine-ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the [source code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax/blob/1a28c57444d035d9101dcced473b81d71bffcde1/src/fakeRequest.js#L249).

The `response.responseHeaders` field is a dictionary of response headers.